# Probability Distributions in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic, probability-distribution

I've a question, in my simulation model I wanted to create some randomness of quantities of agents arrival. In my model the chance is 25% that the quantity is 1, 50% that quantity is 2 and 25% that the quantity is 3. I want to generate these quantities by using the split function of anylogic and than in the split function I want to add a distribution, which gives the values based on this distribution.

But is there a distribution in Anylogic, which fits to this kind of estimations or should I really do it manually. I was already thinking about using a rounded value of a normal distribution, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom distribution to create any shape of distribution you want (it is under the ***Agent*** palette).

In your case, you would need to pick one of type discrete as shown below.
[image]

Then, in the split block you would specify the number of copies as

```
customDistribution()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed a great solution thanks